# Pausing Event Sourced System Commands with Global Variable

Tags: c#, oop, global-variables, cqrs, event-sourcing

In my Event Sourced System, I have an endpoint that administration can use to rebuild read side Databases in the case of some read side inconsistency or corruption.

When this endpoint is hit, I would like to stall (or queue) the regular system commands so they cannot be processed. I want to do this so events are not emitted and read side updates are not made while rebuilding the data stores. If this happened, new (live) event updates could be processed in the middle of the rebuild and put the read side DB in an inconsistent state.

---

I was going to use a static class with some static properties (essentially mocking a *global variable*), but have read this is bad practice.

My questions are:

- *Why is this bad practice in OO design and C#?*
- *What other solutions can I use to accomplish this class communication in place of this global variable?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this bad practice in OO design and C#? (using global variables)

There is a lot of [talks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) about this on the community, but `Very briefly, it makes program state unpredictable.`.

> What other solutions can I use to accomplish this class communication in place of this global variable?

You should not stop the command processing if you only need to rebuild a Readmodel. The Write model should go as usual because it doesn't need data from the read side (unless there are some Sagas also). The clients need the commands to be processed so the rebuilding should be done transparently.

Instead you should create another *instance* of the Readmodel that uses another (temporary) persistence (another database/table/collection/whatever) and use this to rebuild the state. Then, when the rebuilding is done you should replace the old/faulty instance with this new one.

For the transition to be as smooth as possible, the fresh Readmodel should *subscribe* to the event stream even before the rebuilding starts but it should not process any incoming event. Instead it should put them in a **ring buffer**, along with the events that are fetched from the Event store or Event log or whatever event source you are using.

The algorithm for processing events from this ring buffer should be `the oldest one is processed first`. In this way, the new events that are generated by the new commands are not processed until the old events (the one that were generated before the rebuilding started) are processed.

Now that you have a clean Readmodel that is processing the latest events (a catched-up Readmodel) you just need it to replace the faulty Readmodel somehow, i.e. you replace it in you composition root of your application (Dependency injection container). The faulty Readmodel could be now discarded.